Merging jsons as input for AWS SFN startExeuction
I have the following aws step function step defined
"Step": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "Name.$": "$.executionName",
    "StateMachineArn": "${arn}",
    "Input.$": "$"
  }
...

I came across this documentation which illustrates how to associate workflow executions
I tried to apply this in the step above, but I keep getting an error:
InvalidDefinition: Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: The value for the field 'Input.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call at ...
"Step": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "Name.$": "$.executionName",
    "StateMachineArn": "${arn}",
    "Input.$": "States.JsonMerge($, {'AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID': $$.Execution.Id}, false)"
  }
...

not sure what I am doing wrong here

You have to stringify and  escape the object literal you are passing in second arg to JsonMerge.  See the question AWS Step Function JsonMerge new data.

Not sure if the fist $ is meant to be previous input from a step / input that you provide upon executing the sfn, but either way.. You can construct your own json within your Input field like so:
    "Step": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name.$": "$.executionName",
        "StateMachineArn": "${arn}",
        "Input": {
                "PreviousInput.$": "$",
                "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
           }
      }


I want to add that key to the existing input $ so that everything is on the same nesting level

As mentioned by @fedondev - you have to stringify and escape the object literal you are passing in second arg to JsonMerge.  So your Input should look like:
"Input.$": "States.JsonMerge($, States.StringToJson(States.Format('\\{\"AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID\":\"{}\"\\}', $$.Execution.Id)), false)"

